# pixel width not consistent between table elements

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm making an ASP.NET website where I have a table displaying certain information.

All the columns on the table are set to be 150px wide, but for some reason, they're displaying unequally?

Here's a code snippet from my Default.aspx:

```
<table width="900px" border="1px">
   <tr>
      <td align="left" width="150px">Col1</td>
      <td align="left" width="150px">Column2</td>
      <td align="left" width="150px">...</td>
      ...
   <tr>
</table>
```

Given all the strings aren't of equal length, but the height is unrestricted and none of the single words are longer than the 150px space.. even so, some of the shorter words' boxes are smaller than 150px while others are just as short but have boxes larger than the other shorter words.

They kind of look like this:

```
Col1   | Column2      | Blah Stuff | Col4       |
Stuff   | 34          | 345         | 23        |
Other  | 3554        |  3421      | 84
```

It just seems very inconsistent.

Am I specifying the width wrong or is there a better way to make sure my columns are nice and straight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. I'm pretty dumb for overlooking this, but if the width of the table is less than the width of all its columns summed together, then the column widths get messed up!

900px was way less than all my 150px columns added together, so that's why it was looking funky. Changing the value made the columns line up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can put border-right applied to each td.

then also apply border-right:0 for td:last-child